# Hierarchical query find all parents with some filters

Tags: oracle, hierarchical

I've a structure like:

```
CREATE TABLE BUSINESS_UNIT (
  ID NUMBER,
  DESCPRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  TAG VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
);
CREATE TABLE USERS (
  ID NUMBER,
  LOGIN VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
);
CREATE TABLE BU_USERS (
  ID_BU NUMBER,
  ID_USER NUMBER
);
CREATE TABLE BU_TREE (
  ID_BU NUMBER,
  ID_PARENT NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO BUSINESS_UNIT VALUES(1, 'ONE', 'WHITE');
INSERT INTO BUSINESS_UNIT VALUES(2, 'TWO', 'RED');
INSERT INTO BUSINESS_UNIT VALUES(3, 'THREE', 'YELLOW');
INSERT INTO BUSINESS_UNIT VALUES(4, 'FOUR', 'GREEN');
INSERT INTO BUSINESS_UNIT VALUES(5, 'FIVE', 'GREEN');
INSERT INTO BUSINESS_UNIT VALUES(6, 'SIX', 'RED');
INSERT INTO BUSINESS_UNIT VALUES(7, 'SEVEN', 'GREEN');

INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(1, 'USER1');

INSERT INTO BU_USERS VALUES(5, 1);

/*
         ___1w___
     ___2r___    3y___
  __4g       7g       6r
 5g

*/
INSERT INTO BU_TREE VALUES(5, 4);
INSERT INTO BU_TREE VALUES(4, 2);
INSERT INTO BU_TREE VALUES(7, 2);
INSERT INTO BU_TREE VALUES(2, 1);
INSERT INTO BU_TREE VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO BU_TREE VALUES(6, 3);
```

And I have to get `parent` record with `TAG = "RED"`.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT
    B.ID
FROM BUSINESS_UNIT B
INNER JOIN BU_TREE T ON (B.ID = T.ID_BU)
START WITH B.ID = (SELECT ID_BU FROM BU_USERS WHERE ID_USER = 1)
CONNECT BY PRIOR B.ID = T.ID_PARENT
```

But it returns only the "directly" father, that is the 5.

So, for the user one I have to get its *parent red business unit*: the number two.

Why my query doesn't returns all the parents?

Thanks

Comment: I did not check that well, but maybe you need `B.ID = PRIOR T.ID_PARENT`?

Comment: If you use Aleksej's hint You'll get whole path and if You need only last row add `where connect_by_isleaf = 1`.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksej it works, I thought that "connect by prior [expression]" was the sintax of the statement, now I see that `PRIOR` specifies which part is the "parent".

Comment: Also, notice that, with data like your sample ones, if the RED item is the root of the tree, you will not get it, because the root value( 1 in you example) is not returned by the query.

Comment: I can't have that case, anyway I can't uderstand why the root is not returned, it also should satisfy the condition `B.ID = PRIOR T.ID_PARENT`, isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why my query doesn't returns all the parents?

Well, **it does return all the parents**. 
But there is no any parents that meet the condition `CONNECT BY PRIOR B.ID = T.ID_PARENT`, so the query shows only 1 record.

---

Please look at the below query, it shows the whole resultset of the join:

```
SELECT *
FROM BUSINESS_UNIT B
inner JOIN BU_TREE T ON (B.ID = T.ID_BU);

       ID DESCPRIPTI TAG             ID_BU  ID_PARENT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2 TWO        RED                 2          1
         3 THREE      YELLOW              3          1
         4 FOUR       GREEN               4          2
         5 FIVE       GREEN               5          4
         6 SIX        RED                 6          3
         7 SEVEN      GREEN               7          2
```

---

The subquery `(SELECT ID_BU FROM BU_USERS WHERE ID_USER = 1)` gives 5, so your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM BUSINESS_UNIT B
inner JOIN BU_TREE T ON (B.ID = T.ID_BU);
START WITH B.ID = 5
CONNECT BY PRIOR B.ID = T.ID_PARENT;
```

---

WHen running this query, in the frst step Oracle evaluates `START WITH B.ID = 5` conditions, and picks rows that meet this condition, that is:

```
       ID DESCPRIPTI TAG             ID_BU  ID_PARENT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         5 FIVE       GREEN               5          4
```

---

In the next step, oracle applies `CONNECT BY PRIOR B.ID = T.ID_PARENT;` condition to the above "prior" record (taking PRIOR ID = 5 from this record), and then search for records that meet the right side of the condition (5 = ID_PARENT) in the resultset of join.
There is no any record with `parent_id =  5` in the result of join, so the final result of the connect-by query is:

```
        ID      ID_BU  ID_PARENT
---------- ---------- ----------
         5          5          4
```

Comment: Many thanks for the complete explanation, just to complete this answer, the solution (as suggested by  Aleksej) is to move the `PRIOR` clause on the "other side" of `CONNECT BY` expression.